# How do I create n canvases from within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, innerhtml

I am looking for a way to create canvases as I need them at run time. my code so far is

```
    var isCanv = new Array();//bool array for which places in the arrays are/are not in use
    var canv = new Array();//for the canvases
    var ctx = new Array();//for the contexts
    var inhtml = new Array();//for the html canvas tags for each canvas
    var upperBound = -1;//the highest index used so far

    function createCtx(){
      var i = 0;
      while(isCanv[i]){
        i++;
      }
      inhtml[i] = '<canvas id="canv'+i+'" width="'+800+'px" height="'+800+'px" style="display:block;background:#ffffff+;"></canvas>';
      isCanv[i] = true;
      if(i>upperBound){
        upperBound = i;
      }
      var tohtml = '';
      for(var j = 0; j<= upperBound; j++){
        if(isCanv[i]){
          tohtml+=inhtml[j];
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('game').innerHTML=tohtml;
      canv[i] = document.getElementById('canv'+i);
      ctx[i] = canv[i].getContext('2d');
      return(i);
    }

    function keyEvent(event) {
      var i = 0;
      while(isCanv[i]){
        ctx[i].fillStyle="#00FFFF";
        ctx[i].fillRect(0,0,800,800);
        i++;
      }
    }
```

and the html looks like this

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>redicated</title>
      </head>
      <body style="background:#333333;" onkeydown="keyEvent(event)">
        <div id="game"></div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This works for the first canvas, but any subsequent addition breaks it all.
Does anyone know how I could fix this, or of a better way of doing it?

Edit:

I figured it out. I need to recreate the context every time there is an addition. now my code looks like

```
    function createCtx(){
      var i = 0;
      while(isCanv[i]){
        i++;
      }
      inhtml[i] = '<canvas id="canv'+i+'" width="'+800+'px" height="'+800+'px" style="display:block;background:#ffffff+;"></canvas>';
      isCanv[i] = true;
      if(i>upperBound){
        upperBound = i;
      }
      var tohtml = '';
      for(var j = 0; j<= upperBound; j++){
        if(isCanv[j]){
          tohtml+=inhtml[j];
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('game').innerHTML=tohtml;
      for(var j = 0; j<= upperBound; j++){
        if(isCanv[j]){
          canv[j] = document.getElementById('canv'+j);
          ctx[j] = canv[j].getContext('2d');
        }
      }

      return(i);
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling the function that creates the canvases? Your closing tag is `</canas>`, is that a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. now I can use ctx[i].fillRect() on the most resent one, but not those that came before. I am calling createCtx() from the console

Answer (score 0):

The for loop:

```
 for(var j = 0; j<= upperBound; j++){
    if(isCanv[i]){
      tohtml+=inhtml[j];
 }
```

is only ran once since when it is first executed j == upperBound. To fix this try removing

```
  if(i>upperBound){
    upperBound = i;
  }
```

and whats the point of upperBound anyways it will always be equivalent to i so why not just use that.

Comment: later on in the development of this program, I plan on being able to remove canvases as well, creating holes in the array, and instead of shifting all of the later indexes back to fill it, I was planning on just slotting the next one in to take it's place. Also, the second time createCtx() is ran, the loop runs twice, for j=0, and for j=1.